# Google Visualization API ChartWrapper method

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

I'm using Google Visualization API. I would like to use ChartWrapper method. Can someone give me a very simple example using JSON format for getting data?

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Create an empty ChartWrapper and set its properties
            var chart1 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper();
            chart1.setChartType('Table');
            chart1.setContainerId('chart1_div');
            // To set a DataView for the ChartWrapper, use 
            // DataView.toJSON()function. 
            // There is a no need to set DataTable for the ChartWrapper. 
            chart1.setView(dataView1.toJSON());
```